# Querying XML Data stored in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a column called Resume of type XML stored in a table in MS-SQL Server.

I want to retrieve all the candidates who are from the city Saginaw.

When I use the query

```
SELECT Resume.query('(: explicit namespace :)declare namespace ns="Namespace-Resume";
                //ns:Address/ns:Addr.Location/ns:Location/ns:Loc.City')
FROM JobCandidate
```

I get all the values for the city which is fine but when I use the following query:

```
SELECT Resume.query('(: explicit namespace :)declare namespace ns="Namespace-Resume";
                //ns:Location[@ns:Loc.City="Saginaw"]/ns:Name')
FROM JobCandidate
```

I get an error "There is not attribute named Loc.City".

The sample data is as below:

```
<ns:Resume xmlns:ns="Namespace-Resume">
<ns:Name>
    <ns:Name.Prefix></ns:Name.Prefix>
    <ns:Name.First>Shai</ns:Name.First>
    <ns:Name.Middle></ns:Name.Middle>
    <ns:Name.Last>Bassli</ns:Name.Last>
    <ns:Name.Suffix></ns:Name.Suffix>
  </ns:Name>
<ns:Address>
<ns:Addr.Type>Home</ns:Addr.Type>
<ns:Addr.Street>567 3rd Ave</ns:Addr.Street>
<ns:Addr.Location>
  <ns:Location>
    <ns:Loc.CountryRegion>US </ns:Loc.CountryRegion>
    <ns:Loc.State>MI </ns:Loc.State>
    <ns:Loc.City>Saginaw</ns:Loc.City>
  </ns:Location>
</ns:Addr.Location>
</ns:Address>
</ns:Resume>
```

Comment: `Loc.City` is not attribute. It's element.

Comment: Ommit the @ sign in your XPath expression

Comment: I still get the same error when I remove the @ sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not all clear... I'll provide several approaches, one of them will hopefully point you the way (You can copy the whole lot into a query window and execute it *stand-alone*):

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<ns:Resume xmlns:ns="Namespace-Resume">
  <ns:Name>
    <ns:Name.Prefix />
    <ns:Name.First>Shai</ns:Name.First>
    <ns:Name.Middle />
    <ns:Name.Last>Bassli</ns:Name.Last>
    <ns:Name.Suffix />
  </ns:Name>
  <ns:Address>
    <ns:Addr.Type>Home</ns:Addr.Type>
    <ns:Addr.Street>567 3rd Ave</ns:Addr.Street>
    <ns:Addr.Location>
      <ns:Location>
        <ns:Loc.CountryRegion>US </ns:Loc.CountryRegion>
        <ns:Loc.State>MI </ns:Loc.State>
        <ns:Loc.City>Saginaw</ns:Loc.City>
      </ns:Location>
    </ns:Addr.Location>
  </ns:Address>
</ns:Resume>';
```

--Read one element's text with namespaces wildcards

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/*:Resume/*:Name/*:Name.First/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)');
```

--Use a default namespace

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'Namespace-Resume')
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/Resume/Address/Addr.Location/Location/Loc.City/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)');
```

--Your sample XML includes one person only, but I assume there are more
--Use a predicate to get the name for a given location

```
DECLARE @location NVARCHAR(100)=N'Saginaw';--Change this for tests
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'Namespace-Resume')
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/Resume[(Address/Addr.Location/Location/Loc.City/text())[1]=sql:variable("@location")]/Name/Name.First/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)');
```

--Read several values of this node
--Use a predicate to get the name for a given location

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'Namespace-Resume')
SELECT r.value(N'(Name/Name.First/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
      ,r.value(N'(Name/Name.Last/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') 
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/Resume[(Address/Addr.Location/Location/Loc.City/text())[1]=sql:variable("@location")]') AS A(r);
```

### UPDATE: The SELECT you provide in comment

The call to `nodes()` is missing? Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @location NVARCHAR(100)=N'Saginaw'; 
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'Namespace-Resume') 
SELECT r.value(N'(Name/Name.First/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
      ,r.value(N'(Name/Name.Last/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') 
FROM JobCandidate
CROSS APPLY Resume.nodes(N'/Resume[(Address/Addr.Location/Location/Loc.City/text())[1]=sql:variable("@location")]') AS A(r);
```

### UPDATE 2: Namespace according to your comment

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<ns:Resume xmlns:ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume">
  <ns:Name>
    <ns:Name.Prefix />
    <ns:Name.First>Shai</ns:Name.First>
    <ns:Name.Middle />
    <ns:Name.Last>Bassli</ns:Name.Last>
    <ns:Name.Suffix />
  </ns:Name>
  <ns:Address>
    <ns:Addr.Type>Home</ns:Addr.Type>
    <ns:Addr.Street>567 3rd Ave</ns:Addr.Street>
    <ns:Addr.Location>
      <ns:Location>
        <ns:Loc.CountryRegion>US </ns:Loc.CountryRegion>
        <ns:Loc.State>MI </ns:Loc.State>
        <ns:Loc.City>Saginaw</ns:Loc.City>
      </ns:Location>
    </ns:Addr.Location>
  </ns:Address>
</ns:Resume>';
DECLARE @location NVARCHAR(100)=N'Saginaw';--Change this for tests

WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume')
SELECT r.value(N'(Name/Name.First/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)')
      ,r.value(N'(Name/Name.Last/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') 
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/Resume[(Address/Addr.Location/Location/Loc.City/text())[1]=sql:variable("@location")]') AS A(r);
```

Comment: When I used the third option I get the error - 

'text()' is not supported on simple typed or 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#anyType' elements, found 'element({Namespace-Resume}:Loc.City,xs:string) *'..

I removed the [1] on both sides of the "=" sign and still got the error.

Comment: @SQLDev Sorry, I don't know, where this is going wrong... If you copy my code *as is*, it should work. What did you change? Might be usefull, to use the edit option of your question and add some additional information.

Comment: If I use the code as is it works - no issues. But when I tweak it to select it from my table I get the error. This is the code I am using:                                      


    DECLARE @location NVARCHAR(100)=N'Saginaw';
    WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT N'Namespace-Resume')
    SELECT Resume.value(N'(/Resume[(//Address/Addr.Location/Location/Loc.City/text())=sql:variable("@location")]/Name/Name.First/text())',N'nvarchar(max)')
        FROM JobCandidate

Comment: I am still getting the error - but I think I found the issue - the namespace is defined as http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume in my table.

I think its because of the "/" present in the namespace name its throwing the error.

Comment: @SQLDev I don't think so... See my update 2. It is actually not really important, how you define your namespace. But it must be the same for XML and query. If you cannot solve this with an explicit namespace, you might try the *wildcard namespace* like `*:Element`

Comment: I created a temp table and inserted all the values from my main table to the temp table. When I run the query against the temp table I am not getting the error. This led me to believe the data might be somehow corrupted in my table.

I selected each xml value individually and inserted one by one into my temp table and the query works and retrieves the names correctly.

I created a new table with the values from the temp table and when I run the query I got no errors too. 

So the data in the main table is indeed corrupted. Thanks a lot for all your help.